# Cards with image in BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, e-commerce

I would like to build some cards with categories, like: Men, Women and Kids.
I would like to these cards look like these: [image].

I want to let user click on one of them and going to Men or Women page.
Any Ideas how I could do that?

I am using JS, BS, CSS, HTML

Comment: comission on your job ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the HTML CODE For Custom Card

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <div class="custom-card content-left">
                <h3>TOP TRENDING</h3>
                <h1>SPRING TRENDS</h1>
                <h2>Collections</h2>
                <a href="#">Discover NOW</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <div class="custom-card content-center">
                <h3>TOP WANTED TODAY</h3>
                <h1>SPRING TRENDS</h1>
                <h2>Jumpsuit</h2>
                <a href="#">Discover NOW</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <div class="custom-card content-right">
                <h3>SOMETHING NEVER GET OLD</h3>
                <h1>For Men</h1>
                <h2>Collections</h2>
                <a href="#">Discover NOW</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Custom Card Design CSS

```
    /* USE BACKGROUND IMAGE INSTADE OF BACKGROUND COLOR */
    .content-left {
        background-color: tan;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 50% 100%;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 30px 20px;
    }

    .content-center {
        background-color: orange;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 50% 100%;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 30px 20px;

    }

    .content-right {
        background-color: powderblue;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 50% 100%;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 30px 20px;

    }

    /* CARD TEXT STYLE */
    .custom-card h1 {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 900;
        font-size: 28px;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

    .custom-card h2 {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 24px;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 5px 0;
    }

    .custom-card h3 {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: left;

    }

    .custom-card a {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        color: black;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 5px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-bottom-width: 4px;
        border-color: red;

    }
```

Source Code: https://github.com/HassanNazmul/stack-Overflow/blob/main/Cards%20with%20image%20in%20BOOTSTRAP/index.html

Comment: Hey there! Welcome! Would you mind explaining how the code works, so that more people will be helped out later in the future? Thank you!